Can Nm 14/2 be pulled thru armorlite?

I have an older house that is 1920s. I was attempting to replace the old wire box/knob and tube when I noticed they had it buried in the wall from the switch to the ceiling. I have 14/2 nm cable. Can I pull that wire thru armorlite so I won’t have to buy a roll of armorlite tubing? Hope this isn’t confusing question. Appreciate the help.

If it's a section of flex conduit or armored cable, why do you want to replace it with NM?

If you have flex conduit in place, use THHN wires, NOT NM cable.

I’m asking this question because previously, it was by wire (kt) going into the switch up thru buried plastered wall, then to exposed knob and tube between the joist. I want to replace it because the only way I can get power to the switch, which is by my front door is to run 14/2 nm wire from across the room. Hope that makes sense.

Where you located? Somewhere like Chicago that requires armored/metal clad cable? Otherwise, why not just fish the NM itself?

Missouri. And because it was originally buried in plaster. I attached a picture of it helps.
